# CSS3 Rounded and Dotted borders?

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a border in CSS3 such that they are rounded and dotted?

I'm rounding my corners but they appear solid with:

```
border: 1px dotted gray;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 30px 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px 20px;
```

The rest of the border is dotted but the corners are solid.

I understand that this is specific to Firefox but that's fine for now.

Thanks

Comment: We don't need to use the vendor prefixes these days. https://caniuse.com/border-radius

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It'a bug in firefox.see this [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721),mozilla doesn't support rounded corner for dotted and dashed border.

Comment: Five years later and this bug is still there.. :/

Comment: This will be (finally) fixed [in the next release](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/50#CSS) of Firefox coming in november: "Border-radiused corners with dashed and dotted styles are now rendered with the specified style instead of a solid style"

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find a solution by accident.

Here's the code:

```
background-color: none !important;
  border:none !important;
  border-top: 5px dotted #70c1bb !important;
    border-top-width:5px;
    border-right-width:0px;
    border-bottom-width:0px;
    border-left-width:0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, theoretically you can have dotted and rounded borders, but as you have seen practically browsers may not support it yet.

Comment: Yeah I found the bug report - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use multiple background images. You can use this approach to specify a different `background-image` for the four corners.

You may also want to add a fifth image for the centre background image (repeated, if necessary).

Something along the lines of...

```
.dashed-rounded-border {

    border: 2px dashed blue;

    background-image: url("top-left.png"), url("top-right.png"), url("bottom-right.png"), url("bottom-left.png"), url("center.png");
    background-position: left top, right top, right bottom, left bottom, center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;

    -webkit-border-radius: 22px;
    -moz-border-radius: 22px;
    border-radius: 22px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this issue is

```
background: url('../images/dot.png');
background-size: 4px;
background-position: bottom left;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

make sure the dot image is just one dot with some white space on wither side of it. After that you should be good.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote: Using this will work

```
border-style: none;
border-top-style: dotted;
border-width: thick;
```

Answer (score 0):

### **These two lines of code will make your border rounded or dotted.**

- **border: 4px;** we are setting the size of the border to make it more visible ( It is up to you)
- **border-style:dotted none none none;** we are setting **border-top-style: dotted;** and others to **none**

```css
hr{
border: 4px;
border-style:dotted none none none;
/* border-style:none;
  border-top-style: dotted; */
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```