# Making a circle with dotted border in css and animating on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to animate a css circle. When the user hovers it, the border of the circle should become a dotted line and it should animate like a spinning wheel. I can make it spin for a given time, but I couldn't find a way to animate it until the mouse pointer hovers on it and then stop the animation when the mouse pointer is taken out of the circle and make a dotted border.

html

```
<div>
</div>
```

css

```
div {
    background: red;
    border: 5px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
     transform:rotate(180deg);
     border: 5px dotted blue;
}
```

jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/uYBKQ/1/

Comment: You need CSS animations. CSS transitions won't loop.

Comment: How do i make a dotted border? could you help me :)

Comment: I assume you're using Firefox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718215/css3-rounded-and-dotted-borders

Comment: `border: 5px dotted green;` will give you the dotted border

Comment: @TomPietrosanti not in Firefox, like I said

Comment: yes i am using firefox

Comment: @Prinzhorn The syntax is correct for Firefox, but it looks like it won't work on the rounded portion of the border (in firefox).

Comment: And I just learned something :)

Comment: fwiw, there is an open bug for this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need CSS Animations.

In your HTML code, put the follow class:

```
<div class="rotate">
 <!-- The content -->
</div>
```

And in your CSS file, add these rules (this example is only for webkit):

```
div:hover {
     -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uYBKQ/2/)

Cheers, Leo

If you want to works in Firefox, just add the respective vendor prefixes.

Comment: Keep in mind this will only word in modern browsers, you might want to check out http://modernizr.com/. Modernizr checks and replaces non-supported css3 features with javascript.

Comment: I could not have said it better. Thanks @Joe_Maker.

Answer (score 4):

I forked your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vHRat/3/

Here is the updated CSS:

```
div {
    background: red;
    border: 5px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 0%;
}

div:hover {
    border: dotted 5px blue;
    animation: hover 5s;
    -webkit-animation: hover 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
@keyframes hover
{
    from {}
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hover /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    from {}
        to {
            transform:rotate(360deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        }
}
```

Also for what its worth, if you change the border-radius to 0, you can clearly see the rotation.  The border appears as solid and the circle appears static due to the rotation.