# how to make dashed border line move in clockwise when you are hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dashed border around div element :

```
 .dash_border{
        border: dashed;
        stroke: 2px;
        margin:20px;
    }
```

I want to move the dashed lines clockwise when my pointer is on top of the div element and stop when I get out out of that element. How can I do it ?

Comment: You can't do that with CSS only

Comment: How can I use javascript to make animation happen?

Comment: And the animation which is displayed stops or keeps continuing when I hover. How can I stop animation when I don't hover on that div element?

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

div:hover {
     -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
     border: 2px dashed blue;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

```html
   <div class="rotate"></div>
```

This is based on this answer: [Making a circle with dotted border in css and animating on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240759/making-a-circle-with-dotted-border-in-css-and-animating-on-hover).

http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/j4ys9x2L/